# Follow set of a grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

What would the follow set of this grammar be? I haven't encountered a problem like this. Thank you.

```
C -> IV
V -> ;C
V -> lambda
```

the follow(C) = follow(V)
and follow(V) = follow(C)

so I would appreciate help on finding what the follow sets = { }

Comment: It's called a DFA: http://www.cs.odu.edu/~ygongjun/nerzic/390teched/regular/fa/nfa-lambda-2-nfa.html

Comment: I know that the follow set for a grammar like 
     S - > ABC
     A - > a
     A - > lambda
     B - > Bb
     B - > b 
     B - > lambda
     C - > c
  
=====> follow(S) = { $ }
  follow(A) = follow(b,c)
  follow(B) = follow(b,c)
  follow(C) = follow($)

===== > but here there are no dependencies like
    follow(C)= follow(V)
    follow(V) = follow(C)